# Toggle JQuery Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, plugins

I have an image on which I call the zoom effect using imageLens plugin. It works, however I want to toggle the plugin, everytime the text is clicked. I tried using `.toggle()` in many places, but it either toggles the image or the click text but never the plugin. How can I achieve this .

HTML:

```
<li ><a href="#" id="zoom">Pan/Zoom</a></li>
<img src="bg.jpg" id="img1" width="100%" height="100%" style="position: absolute, z-index: -1"/ >
```

Script:

```
$('#zoom').click(function() {
            $('#img1').imageLens({ lensSize: 150 });
    });
```

Comment: What do you mean by toggle the plugin?

Comment: i want the lens zoom effect to toggle .

Answer (score 1):

you can do this with small tweak:

**script:**

```
    var flag=0;
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#img1').imageLens();
     $('#zoom').click(function() {
         flag=flag+1;
         if(flag%2 == 0){
          $('#img1').off();
        }else{
         $('#img1').imageLens({ lensSize: 150 });

          }
            });

     });
```

**html:**

```
<li ><a href="#" id="zoom">Pan/Zoom</a></li>
<img src="bg.jpg" id="img1" width="100%" height="100%" style="position: absolute, z-index: -1" />
```

Comment: doesn't work. i set the value as 0 instead of 150 in normal condition. Is there any way to toggle this particular statement `$('#img1').imageLens({ lensSize: 150 });` on or off .